# Postgres Installer Error : Problem running the post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly

Tags: postgresql

I encountered this error when trying to re-install Postgres.

**Problem running the post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly."

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution in this article:
https://webkul.com/blog/postgresql-windows-installation-problem-running-post-install-step-installation-may-not-complete-correctly/

This worked great so thought I would share here also so I have a place to refer to when I hit this error.

Solution:
1. Uninstall PostgreSQL

2. Run command: net user postgres /delete
3. Click: Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Configure advanced user profile properties -> delete all “Unknown User” instances that seem to be left from PostgreSQL installation.
4. Run command: net user postgres  /add
5. Run: compmgmt.msc -> Click Local Users and Groups -> Users -> postgres ->Member of -> Add… -> Administrators -> OK
6. Run: runas /user:postgres cmd.exe ->
7. change into the directory where your installer is and execute your installer (version may be different)  ***postgresql-8.4.9-1-windows.exe***

installed successfully without errors. Checked data folder and confirmed files created successfully.

8. Run: compmgmt.msc -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> postgres -> Member of -> Administrators -> Remove
   9/ Run: compmgmt.msc -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> postgres -> Member of -> Add… -> Power Users -