PostgreSQL: Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly.The database cluster initialisation failed
On Windows 10 Enterprise, I've been trying to install multiple PostgreSQL versions (v10, v14, v16), but the installer always gives this error:
*Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialization failed.
Inside Services, the PostgreSQL service is not present. *
I've tried multiple variants:

running it with admin rights, not run it with admin
installing under EN-US locale
Installing the /data folder to other location than C:\Program Files
also did all the indications from other discussions like the ones below, but I'm still not able to have a PostgreSQL service in services and to run a database:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308389/postgres-installer-error-problem-running-the-post-install-step-installation-m
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28836/pg-install-the-database-cluster-initialisation-failed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102245/getting-database-cluster-error-while-installing-postgresql-12-on-windows-10/61115811#61115811
Could you please advise on this?
